# Android Play Store Rejection: APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE

Tags: android, privacy-policy

[image]

I have hosted the policy on our website and is also included in the app. In our app, I have a link which goes to our website.
My app runs in App Store but google play store keeps rejecting it without giving more details.

I have no idea how google thinks privacy policy is not hosted properly and they do not even give more detail.s

Comment: Make sure you mention all the things in the privacy policy. Also, if there is a link in the app I hope it opens up in external browser and privacy policy link is not a pdf or any any kind of online document.

Comment: Can you please add the privacy policy URL you has posted in Play Console as well as inside app